# How can I convert a comma-delimited list into a select box

Tags: list, select, coldfusion

I have a variable that has more than one value in it. The output of the list  is like  this:

`Output1, Output2, Output3, Output4, Output5`

I use the the `<cfset varpo = "#output#">`

How can I convert this output to a select box with the value of each options same as the name.

Ps: The output list is automatically gotten from the server in that format.

It's like I haven't seen any answered question to this because none worked.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Updated my tags

Comment: Not related to your question, but if your list is formatted as shown, all elements starting with Output 2 will include the leading space.  That may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<cfset list= "Output1, Output2, Output3, Output4, Output5" />  
<cfset arr = listToArray (list, ",") />
<cfset len = ArrayLen( arr ) />
<select>
  <cfloop from="1" to="#len#" index="idx" >
    <option><cfoutput>#arr[idx]#</cfoutput></option>
  </cfloop>
</select>
```

OR

```
<select>
  <cfloop list="Output1, Output2, Output3, Output4, Output5" index="item">
    <option><cfoutput>#item#</cfoutput></option>
   </cfloop>
</select>
```

Comment: Too complicated.  Why not simply loop through the list?

Comment: Thanks @user3733648

Comment: The documentation on `cfloop` is on the web and has all sorts of examples.

Comment: I would add that I would want to uses `item.trim()` . I am concerned that I would get unexpected spaces